# Edit and Delete options for each sharepoint list item using query Datatables?

Tags: javascript, rest, jquery, sharepoint-rest-api

How to use jquery Datatables to add - Edit and Delete options for each sharepoint list item. Please help me with an example.

Comment: Have you tried anything along API (to retrieve and update items and to get list schemas)?